# Is it possible to merge unique keys

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

I have two tables (parent, child).

the tables contain data as follows

```
test (child) 

type      version
--------  -------
bmw       M3
audi      RS6
mercedes  S500
audi      RS4
bmw       M3
audi      RS6

test2 (parent)

type     version (type & version are a combined unique key)
-------- -------
audi     RS4
audi     RS6
mercedes S500
bmw      M3
```

These two tables are linked by foreign keys (type,version) and an update on test2 cascades on test. This works flawlessly.

However, I want to be able to change a version in test2 to an identical version in test2 (see below). As type/version are a combined unique key I do get the duplicate key warning which is logic. Is there a clever way around that staying with this concept? I can do it with normal SQL updates etc, but would like to try with foreign keys.

The result should be as follows. Change parent value of RS6 to RS4

```
test (child) 

type      version
--------  -------
bmw       M3
audi      RS4
mercedes  S500
audi      RS4
bmw       M3
audi      RS4

test2 (parent)

type     version
-------- -------
audi     RS4
mercedes S500
bmw      M3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with two queries:

- first change the version of audi RS4 to RS6 in the child table (that will work since the parent already exists)
- then delete parent audi RS6 (this will not affect the child table since no child relates to that parent anymore)

Queries:

```
update test set version = 'RS4' where type = 'audi' and version = 'RS6';
delete from test2 where type = 'audi' and version = 'RS6';
```

Comment: See my comment @Bill Karwin

Comment: @blackswan: you are looking to remove a record from the parent table... an `update` query cannot do that.

Comment: I wouldn't even mind it staying (without deleting it), I just would like to move all the child keys to the other primary key. But I guess this only works with conventional SQL as you and Bill mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
UPDATE test SET type = 'audi', version = 'RS4'
WHERE type = 'audi' AND version = 'RS6';
```

It would even work like this, since you're only changing one of the columns:

```
UPDATE test SET version = 'RS4'
WHERE type = 'audi' AND version = 'RS6';
```

As long as the two columns in the child table reference a row that exists in the parent table before and after the UPDATE, it's okay.

---

Re your comment:

No, there's no way to do what you describe in one step.

You would have to do it this way:

1. Change any rows in `test` that depend on the parent row you want to merge.

   ```
   UPDATE test SET type = 'audi', version = 'RS4'
   WHERE type = 'audi' AND version = 'RS6';
   ```
2. Delete the parent row, after there are no child rows left that depend on it.

   ```
   DELETE test2 WHERE type = 'audi' AND version = 'RS6';
   ```

Comment: Yep, I know how to do it that way. But, is there no way doing it starting with an update on test2? something like an update on duplicate key thingy? My intention is to use test2 as an admin table where I can change value and have the general overview.